# Applying a regex to a single column in TSV format w/ shell script

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I have a file that's TSV that I want to pipe into a script and modify only one column (in place) and leave the rest of the data in tact.

Sample row:

```
column1 column2 1   2   3
```

I would want to apply a regex to column2 for example (but leave it in place)

**UPDATE** I don't think I made this very clear in my original post, I'll actually want to do **two** replacements on the same column

A very simple attempt I have would be

```
while read line; do
  echo $line | cut -f2 | sed 's/col/something_else/g' | sed 's/mn//g'
done
```

This modifies the column that I want.  But I'm having trouble re-creating the rest of the data from the original row.  I'm fine using `awk` (though I'm not well versed in it).  Real requirement is to run this in a shell command (on linux)

The desired output would be

```
column1 something_else2 1   2   3
```

Comment: Try something like `awk '{gsub(/regex/, "replacement", $2)}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. If you need to replace with backreferences, you will need `gensub` instead of `gsub` though.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: inplace is a nice word for _Save in temporary and move_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gnu awk` supports inplace editing so you may just use this command and save changes back to file:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {
sub(/col/, "something_else", $2); sub(/mn/, "", $2)} 1' file
```

Here are `awk` command details:

- `-i inplace` enables inplace editing in `gnu awk`
- `-F '\t'`: Uses tab as input field separator
- `$n` represents nth column in a record so `$2` becomes 2nd column
- `1` is default action in `awk` to print full record

If you are not using `gnu awk` then use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {
sub(/col/, "something_else", $2); sub(/mn/, "", $2)} 1' file>file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Another option is to use `sed` with inplace editing:

```
sed -i.bak -E $'s/^([^\t]+\t)col/\\1something_else/' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Could you add some more clarity around the syntax in the first solution?  Particularly the meaning/purpose of `$2` and `1`?

Comment: Also updated my question because I don't think it was clear in the first rev.  I will want to do two replacements, does your solution suppor that?

Comment: I just added the expected output for the example case

Comment: Well that's the way it's effectively happening in this example.  In reality what I'm trying to do is do two different regex replacements on a single column (was trying to keep the column simple).  One will remove guids and one will replace a specifc text identifier found by a regex

Comment: ok I have already provided 2 replacements in same column example in my answer. Please try that.

Comment: Well one difference between your solution and my post is in mine I'm reading a file line by line in a stream style, yours seems batch, does `awk` not support that and working with a variable?

Comment: I highly recommend reading about awk. `awk` is a replacement for the loop you're running in shell. awk also does it line by line not in a batch. Every record is represented by variable `$0` inside awk.

Comment: Understood but if I'm using this in something connected by `|` wouldn't it have to wait until the entire file is processed

Comment: Sorry not sure if I understood your comment. You can use pipeline with awk like your shell loop i.e. `your_command | awk ...`

Comment: awk supports streams.

Comment: @sedavidw how are you imagining you'd do "inplace" editing of a stream? What does "inplace" mean in that context?

Comment: "In place" might be the wrong phrasing there.  But with the TSV input I wanted it to output the TSV with the regex done on a singe column, so when I said "in place" perhaps my brain was thinking of the exact string it would be working on